# Create a 3 Field Form within a Session with Cache stored to it

Tags: c#, session, caching, model-view-controller, session-state

I am to create a form with 3 fields (FirstName, LastName, and Quantity Ordered). This form is also supposed to be in a session state. Also, I am to save cache from the session, and the cache is supposed to store the accumulated orders. Then the form posts to a new page with results, including the cache of total orders. I am using C# / MVC / VisualStudio, but am a beginner so there is a good chance I have lots of extra syntax (or lack there of) that isn't necessary. Here is what I have so far:

MODEL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState; //for session
using System.Web.UI;



namespace SessionPractice.Models

{
public sealed class HttpSessionState
{

    public string FirstName     { get; set; }
    public string LastName      { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOrdered  { get; set; }
    public int QuantityTotal    { get; set; }




}
public class UserSession1
{
    public string FirstName     { get; set; }
    public string LastName      { get; set; }
    public int QuantityOrdered  { get; set; }
    public int QuantityTotal { get; set; }
}



}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.SessionState; //for session
using System.Web.UI;           //for cache
using SessionPractice.Models;




namespace SessionPractice.Controllers
{
    [SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Default)]
    public class SessionPracticeController : Controller
    {

        void Session_Start (object sender, EventArgs e) //?
        {

        }

        // GET: SessionPractice
        public ActionResult Session1()
        {
            UserSession1 model = new UserSession1();
            return View(model);
        }

        [OutputCache(Duration = 30, Location = OutputCacheLocation.Client, VaryByParam = "none")]
        public ActionResult FormSubmit(UserSession1 sp)
        {
            UserSession1 cache = new UserSession1();
            return View(sp);

        }



        void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


    }
}


namespace SessionPractice.Cache
{
    public class UserSession1
    {
        public int QuantityTotal { get; set; }
    }

}
```

VIEW 1:

```
    @{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    <script>

        Session["FirstName"] = FirstName;
        Session["LastName"] = LastName;
        Session["QuantityOrdered"] = QuantityOrdered;
        Session["QuantityTotal"] = QuantityTotal;

        var FirstName = (String)(Session[FirstName]);
        var LastName = (String)(Session[LastName]);
        var QuantityOrdered = (Int)(Session[QuantityOrdered]);
        var QuantityTotal = (Int)(Session[QuantityTotal]);



    </script>

    <title>Session1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Please fill out the following form.</h2>

    <form method="post" action="FormSubmit" onsubmit="return(sp) ">

        First Name:
        <br />
        <input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName">
        <br />
        Last Name:
        <br />
        <input id="LastName" type="text" name="LastName">
        <br />
        Quantity Ordered:
        <br />
        <input id="QuantityOrdered" type="text" name="QuantityOrdered" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

VIEW 2:

```
    @model SessionPractice.Models.UserSession1



@{
    Layout = null;

}

@if (Model != null)
{
    <span>First Name:</span>
    <span>@Model.FirstName</span>
    <br />
    <span>Last Name:</span>
    <span>@Model.LastName</span>
    <br />
    <span>Quantity Ordered:</span>
    <span>@Model.QuantityOrdered</span>
    <br />
    <span>Total Quantity Ordered (so far):</span>

    <span>@Model.QuantityTotal</span>
    <br />


}   

@if (Cache !=null)
{
    var QuantityOrdered = Cache.Count; //?

    for (int QuantityTotal = 0; QuantityOrdered < QuantityTotal++; )
    {


        <br />
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what is happening with your code compared to what is supposed to happen?

Comment: Turns out I was all over the place, once I finally broke it down to using only one method of caching I was successful